# Sessions variables do not always keep their values

Tags: php, session-variables, code-snippets, modx, modx-revolution

I set a few session variables in a prehook of Quip Extra in MODX2.8.

`$_SESSION["name"] = value`

After Quip redirects to the next page, I read those variables in another snippet. Sometimes the variables have values, sometimes not. I have not found any logic.

I also added session_start() but the same behaviour. I have done debugging and the missing values of the session variables are the problem and the other code should be fine.

What is the right way to use session variables in MODX?

Comment: It seems there is a delay. After Quip's redirect, it takes some time before the session variables are available. Is there a way how I can force MODX to save session variables immediately after setting them up? Probably, the saving starts normally after the redirect. And then they are not always ready yet when a new page is being processed.

Comment: Sessions in modx work in the same way as any other PHP script. Modx handles starting the session, so there is no need to start it yourself. Do you know if the Quip extra uses ajax by any chance?  That could explain a short delay.

Comment: No it does not use ajax. It redirect itself back to the same page with an extra GET parameter. I guess MODX saves the session data at the end of the script but the redirect is already in progress before the session data has been saved.

Comment: @BramVerstraten, I was starting to think more about your ajax question and recalled that my own Quip prehook code makes a curl call. The session variable is set based on the call result. Could that affect somehow?

Comment: I also turned cache_db_session in MODX off and I was able to make more than 20 test runs without this issue. It still does not guarantee that I found the reason because the problem has random nature.

Comment: cache_db_session could be the issue here. As stated in the documentation it is important to redirect back with the same page headers: https://docs.modx.com/3.x/en/building-sites/settings/cache_db_session

Comment: @BramVerstraten, cache_db_session is the issue. When I turned it off, I could not reproduce the problem. I don't want to modify Quip's code myself so I can't change how Quip redirects. Is there any simple way to clear the entry from the session cache if I know the session id?

Comment: The session data is not lost, only the latest changes are (sometimes) delayed a few seconds when cache_db_session is on. So the redirect sends the correct headers.

Comment: For others who come here: If your $_SESSION variables are not persisting. Check  the URL in the browser's address bar. It there is a redirect or forward to a different domain (e.g., www to non-www or vice versa), session variables will be lost.